# about mysql index, multi-column or one?

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, indexing

I have a sql like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE column_a = sth AND colun_b > sth
```

so, how do I create index for it?

- One index for two column
- Two indexes for each column

which is better?

Comment: I think that in order to get a full answer you need to be more specific about the data that is contained in those columns. Do they have unique values? What type are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are optimizing for exactly that one query, then `a` will be the best optimization. Your `WHERE` clause will check `column_a` first, and the proceed to the next row if that isn't a match. It will only proceed to check `column_b` if it *is* a match at `column_a`. Therefore, you want an index that is sorted by `column_a` first, and then by `column_b`, rather than two separate indexes.

Consider this as opposed to an `OR` clause, where you would generally have wanted two separate indexes, because `OR` says, "first select all the matches for `column_a` and *then* select all the matches for `column_b`, independently, and finally merge the result sets together". Since that query doesn't use feedback from `column_a` when it checks `column_b`, you want to use distinct indexes there.

Also note that this is all written in very general terms. These things may change from case to case depending on what your data looks like. One good way is to create one index, see how performance is, drop it, create the other, and choose the best one.

Comment: No, it should not "proceed to the next row if it doesn't match"; you want an index which it will RANGE SCAN.

Comment: Indeed, "proceed" implies walking over the table, which is what happens when you don't have indexes at all.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remeber is that an MySql index for 2 or more column in the same index work in order that you have made your index.

So to be optimized you have to put your column_a first in the index and then colun_b.
This is to avoid a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

To have better reading you should have one index on two columns if your query is including both the comparisons.

However, you may create another index on second column if your query has only second column in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You want an index which can be RANGE SCANNED. Use EXPLAIN (see the doc), it is your friend.

An index on column_a,column_b should be able to be range scanned in this case, but always check EXPLAIN. Use EXPLAIN on a non-production database with the same schema and volume/distribution of data as your production system (will be)